# Get value of control point if weight is zero.

Tags: bezier-curve

In a rational Bezier curve, the weighted control points are given as
$$\mathbf{P}^w=(wx, wy, wz, w)=(X,Y,Z,W).$$
We can extract the control point $\mathbf{P}$ from $\mathbf{P}^w$ by dividing each of the coordinates in $\mathbf{P}^w$ by the last coordinate $w$.  That is,
$$\mathbf{P} = (X/W,Y/W,Z/W)=(wx/w,wy/w,wz/w)=(x,y,z).$$

But how do we get $\mathbf{P}$ if $w$ is equal to zero?  The NURBS Book says that $\mathbf{P}=\text{direction}(X,Y,Z)$ in this case without explaining what $\text{direction}(X,Y,Z)$ means.  Can somebody explain it to me, please?

Comment: I presume this is referring to the direction $(X,Y,Z)$ is pointing to - in other words, the normalised $(X,Y,Z)$.

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, but I couldn't decide if it made sense or not.

Comment: It does make sense. The weighted control points are given in homogenous coordinates, which reduce to regular coordinates when $w=1$. The advantage of using them is that they allow the encoding of points at infinity when $w=0$, and those points naturally relate to lines through the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The homogeneous coordinates $(x,y,z,0)$ represent a vector in the direction $(x,y,z)$. Or alternatively, they represent a "point at infinity" in the direction $(x,y,z)$.

This should make sense. Take the point with homogeneous coordinates $(wx,wy,wz,w)$, and let $w$ tend towards zero. As the value of $w$ decreases, the point $(x/w,y/w,z/w)$ moves along a line through the origin in the direction of the vector $(x,y,z)$. As $w$ approaches zero, the point goes to infinity.